# How to create below design in css

Tags: html, css, shapes

I am facing issue to create the below shape in css I have no idea how to creat the following shape please help me.
[image]

Comment: since it has a gradient, which makes it quite complex, I would go with creating white svg that would be positioned at right bottom corner